# CentOS 7:Reoccurring failure in accessing AD member samba shares

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos, gssapi

I have a Samba 4.6.2 samba ActiveDirectory member server. Every month or so, all clients lose the ability to connect to all the shares. I can work around the issue by leaving the domain, deleting the machine account, and re-joining the domain, but it is obviously wrong that I have to do this every few weeks.
I thought that it was a machine account password expiration issue, but running
**adcli update** does not help. I tried changing the Group Policy for machine password expiration, but that did not help either.

- Centos 7.4.1708
- Samba 4.6.2
- sssd-krb5-1.15.2
- SSSD 1.15.2-50
- realmd-0.16.1-9

The error message on the client side is

```
"\\cheetoes is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
Login Failure: The target account name is incorrect"
```

On the server side, at startup, log.smbd contains:

```
[2018/05/09 12:03:41.622878,  0] ../source3/libads/kerberos_util.c:74(ads_kinit_password)
  kerberos_kinit_password CHEETOES$@HYMESRUZICKA.ORG failed: Preauthentication failed
[2018/05/09 12:03:41.622923,  1] ../source3/libads/sasl.c:821(ads_sasl_spnego_bind)
  ads_sasl_spnego_gensec_bind(KRB5) failed for ldap/true-companion.hymesruzicka.org with user[CHEETOES$] realm=[HYMESRUZICKA.ORG]: Preauthentication failed
```

And the per-client log shows:

```
[2018/05/09 12:06:58.259646,  1] ../source3/librpc/crypto/gse.c:646(gse_get_server_auth_token)
  gss_accept_sec_context failed with [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Request ticket server cifs/CHEETOES.hymesruzicka.org@HYMESRUZICKA.ORG not found in keytab (ticket kvno 3)]
[2018/05/09 12:06:59.099902,  1] ../source3/librpc/crypto/gse.c:646(gse_get_server_auth_token)
  gss_accept_sec_context failed with [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Request ticket server cifs/CHEETOES.hymesruzicka.org@HYMESRUZICKA.ORG not found in keytab (ticket kvno 3)]
```

Immediately after I rejoin, I do not get the client failures, nor the "Preauthentication failed" error in the log.smbd.
I'm particularly puzzled why rejoining works, but only for a while.

Comment: I assumed this is really that the keytab entries in krb5.keytab are lost / bad / invalidated / expired, but that did not help me find a way to fix the problem.

Comment: Searching long on an unrelated issue, I discovered that adcli is segfaulting several times every day. Adcli is supposed to be the ting which updates the machine password. Don't know if this is root cause, or how I should get patched version: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS 7 builds of Samba are very broken in an Active Directory context. The CentOS build of Samba 4.8.3 results in `adcli` dumping core when the 'update' subcommand is attempted. `adcli` also fails to join or leave the domain correctly, and wrecks 
/etc/samba/smb.conf, as well as the `sssd` and `pam` configs.

And it's not just `adcli`. `realmd`, `winbind`, and `smbd` itself do not work correctly with Windows Active Directory servers, leaving some clients (such as iOS devices) unable to connect.
The only workaround I found is to build a "stock" samba stack, and adcli+reamld from the latest release sources, and use that over the CentOS samba stack. You must also disable updates for all samba components in /etc/yum.conf, otherwise your local samba installation will be broken by the CentOS one. Your yum.conf file needs at least:

```
exclude=adcli-* libsmbclient-* libwbclient* python-smbc-* realmd-* samba-* samba-client-* samba-client-libs-* samba-common-* samba-common-libs-* samba\
-common-tools-* samba-libs-* samba-python-* samba-winbind-* samba-winbind-clients-* samba-winbind-modules-*
```

Note that it's not practical to uninstall CentOS's samba, because many other packages depend upon it.